# Workflows allow Argument definitions but not Workflow Services?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I've been working with WF 4 quite extensively the last handful of months and I've noticed that on the WF designer there is an "Argument" button you can click and then view the list and/or add additional args.

It would be real beneficial to add arguments to a WF Service but in the designer you do not have the same option. Is it possible to define arguments in the XAML or is there a certain reason why arguments are not permitted?

I want to pass in arguments to a Workflow Service that I constructed with the designer. Ideally, I'd like to pass in a string argument into the WF Service from the application which is hosting it (a Win Service). The same application also hosts a Xaml Workflow which I pass in several arguments to allow the WF to do it's job while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a workflow service you start the workflow using a WCF request modeled using the Receive activity. So the Receive activity is where you want to add arguments.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want to pass in an argument from the hosting application when the comm service instantiates during application start up. See my newly edited question to see what I mean.

Comment: @Preet, what didn't make sense before?

Comment: @jlafay But with a workflow service your host doesn't start the workflow, it only enables them to be started by WCF requests. But if you want to provide settings you can use static properties and use VB expressions to load those values.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of. I was aware that the host didn't start it but wasn't sure if you could pass arguments into the host to pass on to the service when needed. The static property is an excellent suggestion, thank you.